# What is the best way to move money to the US from Brazil?

Tags: united-states, currency, moving, brazil

I just got married and my wife is moving with me to the US. We have been living in Brazil together for 2 years and have some savings. What is the best way to move $10.000 to $15.000 to a US account and get a good exchange rate?

Comment: You should talk with a tax accountant about the tax ramifications of the transfer from a US and Brazilian perspective.  I used to work in international tax and Brazil is known for having regulations that are unusual and strict compared with other countries.

Answer (score 1):

Just a regular bank transfer. Call your US bank and ask for wire transfer instructions. I've transferred money like that from US to Europe and back a few times. Usually fees were in low two digits ($15-$30), but depending on your bank account a sending and receiving side may charge a fee.